# Отправка формы из GitHub pages на PHP хостинг с помощью AJAX(XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, github-pages

Есть форма обратной связи:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="https://url.000webhostapp.com/form/configs/form.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-first">
      <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      <input type="text" name="email" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="subject" name="subject" value="">
    <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

XMLHttpRequest:

```
const form = document.getElementById('contact_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const action = document.getElementById('contact_form').getAttribute('action');
  xhr.open('POST', action, true);
  let data = new FormData(form);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.onload = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             console.log(xhr.responseText);
      };
   };
  xhr.send(data);
});
```

form.php(скрипт не итоговый, добавил эти строки, чтобы проверить работоспособность):

```
<?php
  $object = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $request = json_decode($object);
  echo $request;
?>
```

Но ничего не работает и я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
POST https://url.000webhostapp.com/form/configs/form.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Консоль показывает ошибку в предпоследней строке (`xhr.send (data);`).

Есть идеи как можно исправить? Обычный POST запрос с сабмитом работает, а вот AJAX не хочет.

[image: img_1]
[image: img_2]
[image: img_3]

Comment: это не кроссдоменный запрос? Content-Length отправлял?

Comment: Да, кроссдоменный запрос. С github pages на другой хостинг с поддержкой php. Content-Length скорее всего не отправлял, впервые делаю AJAX request на другой сайт. Можно подробнее? В чем именно ошибка? Либо ссылку на какой ни будь материал по этой теме?

Comment: почитай про CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B тут почеловечнее написано https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-cors-20a97786c18c